# How to Auto-switch Text-to-speech Voices on basis of language tags in text

Tags: internationalization, language

Is anyone aware of a TTS system for Mac which will automatically switch voices on the basis of language tags present in word processing or html text?  For example, it would switch to a French voice to correctly pronounce a French word or text run in a longer English text.

I'm looking for an extension or service that could speak a web page or email text coded like

```
<span lang="en-US">In Paris the name of the city is pronounced</span> <span lang="fr-FR">Paris</span>
```

and switch from an English to a French voice for the last word.

It doesn't appear that Apple's own text-to-speech system will do this, voices normally have to be changed by the user (except possibly when the languages are in different scripts, like English and Hebrew).

I have found one app, [Ghostreader +](http://www.convenienceware.com/ghostreader), which does the voice switching, but it requires using the app to add its own language tags and docs are saved in its own non-standard format.  Something which works with tags already present for example in html would be a lot more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own swift binary and use it in Automator. Here's the example code:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class Synth: NSObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    init(text: String) {
        super.init()
        let languageCode = NSLinguisticTagger.dominantLanguage(for: text) ?? AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceIdentifierAlex

        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: languageCode)
        synthesizer.delegate = self
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }

    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        exit(0)
    }
}

var text = CommandLine.arguments.dropFirst().reduce("", +)
text = text.isEmpty ? "No text" : text
let s = Synth(text: text)

RunLoop.main.run()
```

Save it in file called `main.swift` and then in commandline run

```
swiftc main.swift -o ttslanguage
```

Place `ttslanguage` in your home dir, then open Automator.app, select "Service" as a type. Make it run on text input. Place "Run shell script" as a first block and input:

```
~/ttslanguage "$1"
```

Now You'll be able to run Text To Speech that detects the language in selected text.

If the text has multuple sentences with different languages you can change the `Synth` class to (don't forget to `import NaturalLanguage`):

```
class Synth: NSObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    var lastUtterance: AVSpeechUtterance?

    init(text: String) {
        super.init()
        let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.language])
        tagger.string = text
        var utterances = [AVSpeechUtterance]()
        tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .sentence, scheme: .language, options: []) { tag, tokenRange in
                let txt = String(text[tokenRange])
                let languageCode = NSLinguisticTagger.dominantLanguage(for: txt) ?? AVSpeechSynthesisVoiceIdentifierAlex

                let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: txt)
                utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: languageCode)
                utterances.append(utterance)
            return true
        }
        synthesizer.delegate = self

        lastUtterance = utterances.last
        for utterance in utterances {
            synthesizer.speak(utterance)
        }
    }

    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        guard let lastUtterance = lastUtterance else {
            exit(-1)
        }
        if lastUtterance == utterance {
            exit(0)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Project with advanced parsing (including HTML + `lang` attributes) can be found [on github page](https://github.com/slozo/TTSLanguage). More info in README.

Comment: @TomGewecke in order to compile the second `Synth` class you have to add `import NaturalLanguage` under `import AVFoundation` NOTE - it's available since macOS 10.14

Comment: @TomGewecke can you please add sample text to your question? Also can you try to run `~/ttslanguage "hello my friend! Bonjour camarade! Cześć kolego"` in Terminal?

Comment: Ah Ok, I get it. My second implementation works only with "sentences" not single words. For your example HTML parsing would be needed instead.

Comment: @TomGewecke If you are selecting the exact HTML you've posted you can use https://github.com/slozo/TTSLanguage/tree/main , I don't know how to get HTML tags from selected text in Safari :( So I'm using web inspector to select the text and use the Service. Above app parses the HTML, so it reads only the inner text. Please let me know if this is what you need etc. :)

Comment: That's strange `AVFoundation` should be always available in the system. There's precompiled version of the tool zipped in playground Resources (if you trust compiled stuff ;)  Just move TTSLanguage and TTSLanguageLib.framework together somewhere (for example $HOME dir).  BTW If needed I can get rid of the `.framework` dir altogether (I've left it because of the playground tests)

Comment: Home is  where I have them now.  But on my Catalina,  AVFAudio.framework is apparently inside system/library/frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/Frameworks and the path in the app is different.

Comment: That's strange, this framework should be loaded automatically. I've changed "deployment target" to macOS 10.14 (.zip file is also updated)

Comment: It's still looking for System/Library/Frameworks/AVFAudio.framework which doesn't exist.

Comment: I see, there's an issue when the app is built on M1 macs in Monterey. I've added `import AVFAudio` + changed global deployment target to 10.14 maybe that helps..

Comment: Also I've updated the "build" command in README. basically you can run something like: `xcodebuild -workspace TTSLanguage.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme TTSLanguage archive -archivePath $PWD/build/TTSLanguage.xcarchive && open build/TTSLanguage.xcarchive/Products/usr/local/bin/ `

Comment: Still doesn't work in Catalina, but works fine in Monterey, which is good enough.  Thanks for all your effort, I have learned a lot!