# Get the system to use the correct language with the "speak selection" feature

Tags: macos, internationalization, language, monterey, voiceover

I'm trying to use OS X's native voice-recognition system to speak the highlighted text using the correct language.

I enabled System Preferences > Accessibility > Spoken Content > Speak selection, keeping the default of <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

In some cases, the system will correctly identify the non-English words and will speak them with the correct accent, using a different voice (female; German): `ich schreibe`.

In other cases, the system will not correctly identify the non-English words and will speak them with the default voice (male; English): `ich spreche`.

Is there a way to tune this?

Comment: Hmm, so as an example the words « the weekend ». Should they be spoken in English? Or in French since the French happily use them? What about « entrepreneur » use the French voice or the English? Can’t use American because they don’t know where it comes from…

Comment: `ich spreche`, isn't English, so that should be easily identified as German and spoken that way.  The ambiguity of the others are understandable.

Comment: So what about « gestalt » English or German?

Comment: Yes, I understand the occasional ambiguity--in that case, use the default language.  But in this situation, there's no ambiguity.  As such, use the correct language.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  Automatic voice switching is a challenge even for text which is tagged by language.  See this earlier question:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434992/how-to-auto-switch-text-to-speech-voices-on-basis-of-language-tags-in-text